# Single Tomcat GUI or Manager for multiple Tomcat instances

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I was going through [Tomcat setup for setting up multiple instances](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) but could not figure out how we can configure a single tomcat GUI or manager for all the instances so that i can have a list of applications that are setup on different tomcat instances.

Please note that each of these instances have different applications running on different ports.

Please help!! Also please let me know if its not feasible.

---

Second approach: We can have apps listening on different ports by deploying them in separate appBase folders.

Example:

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
    <!--<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />-->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>

        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="Catalina2">
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
    <!--<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />-->
    <Engine name="Catalina2" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>

        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps2"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

is it possible to view all those apps deployed in both appBase folders in one manager app?

Comment: I'm scared it's not possible, the manager webapp (or a PSI PROBE) can only see the other webapps of the same instance. Ask yourself why you need several instances, is it better than one huge standalone Tomcat ? We don't know what you what to achieve, maybe scripting around Apache ANT is a workaround ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell Thanks for replying. Lets say i go ahead with a standalone tomcat server. If i duplicate service tag in apache-tomcat-9.0.19\conf\server.xml and update the ports with new ones for the new service xml tags, then is it possible to view them as well in manager app? Because i don't see it in the manager app for those defined in different connector (with different ports). I will try to post a sample for this case.

Comment: I don't find any solution with Tomcat only. In such cases, we usually use a reverse-proxy in front of Tomcat (Apache). The documentation says the manager doesn't work with virtual host (you are not using virtual hosts but several services, which at the end give the same result).